# Is it unethical to buy cocaine?

Tags: ethics, politics

Put aside any considerations on personal health etc, is it unethical to buy cocaine?

Things to consider in no particular order:

- the drug cartels in the cocaine-producing countries are ruthless, criminal people that torture and kill each other (and possibly unrelated civilisians) in a brutal fashion
- the violence within that 'trade' is mostly attributable to the prohibition of drugs within the societies that demand those drugs the most
- coca farmers do make a living that they couldn't make producing cocoa or coffee; cocaine consumtion transfers some wealth from me to them
- low-level smugglers and peddlers are ruining or even losing their lives bringing cocaine to my country
- as a first world country we are imposing rules and social conventions on what to produce and how to impose drug policies on developing countries via our economic power ('we will support you if ... ')
- lots of the 'truths' about cocaine production are anti-drug myths from the Reagan era ('they use children for this and that')

  - many more implication that havent thought about

So if I was to buy some cocaine, would that be morally objectible? Would I be responsible for people suffering?

Please add more aspects to this question and state you opinion.

Comment: you didn't ask about e.g. sweat shops (is it morally objectionable). your question doesn't read like a philosophy one, but sociological

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN How is it not philosophical / ethical if I ask for the consequences of my actions?

Comment: i suppose it might be an ethical question, but it looks like you're asking about what cocaine production is and does, rather than whether that makes it unethical. i suppose it may be my imagination - the research is into the nuances of sociology, rather than philosophy anyway. you may like http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/doing-allowing/ but i don't know if that'd cover the quetsion, or i'd just answer

Comment: you could try reframing the question based on pages like this https://philosophy.tamucc.edu/extended_examples_marijuana?destination=node%2F1197 i might edit the question, but it'll take a while to get it so it reads like the site wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly there is cocaine produced for ordinary legal use, like eye surgery.  Would it be harmful if you were to illegally buy cocaine stolen from a surgical center's pharmacy?  Would the purchase of that cocaine matter less than the purchase of criminally produced cocaine?  Can you tell the difference?  And if there were no illegal market for the legally produced cocaine, would the unregulated production even exist?  We got to this point from a purely legal Victorian import trade that was only oppressive, and not deadly.

Social situations also adapt to the composite needs that drive them.  We do not know that this situation is *necessarily* this way, and could not be arranged in a totally different way, given a different pattern of use.

You seem convinced that specific consideration of existing consequences is the right way of making this decision, but in making that assumption you are taking upon yourself the recovery of information that is lost or hidden and the prediction of actions which no one can trace or control.

So, I suggest that the first way one should always address something like this is from a reasonable approximation of a Kantian point of view.  If it is already a bad idea from there, then it cannot become a better idea by looking at further factors, only a worse one.  If it is ambiguous from a fairly abstract point of view, THEN we should work outward, and look at other issues.

Even in most such cases, we should not judge the behavior, but the implementations around it, and we should see if they can be rendered morally safe.  Eating meat is not immoral just because factory farming is cruel.  It should just be more expensive.  Americans don't need food prices so low we all get diabetes, anyway...  By judging actions on the basis of their current implementations you discard a moral duty to do adequate moral maintenance of the institutions around us.

Before considering larger and larger circles of effects, it pays to start from the point where you have the most control and the most responsibility, and it pays to look at those in terms of motivation and realistic knowledge.

So I am rejecting your framing, and I am going to answer the question without it.

---

From an individual, naturalistic point of view, what is it that makes this substance special?

1. It is an artificially concentrated version of a naturally occurring substance, which is resource intensive.
2. It is physically addictive, so reducing usage is hard, when one needs to adapt to outside circumstances.
3. It is also psychologically habituating, so there is a strong trend for dosages to increase simply due to availability, without the active consideration of the user.

From a naturalistic version of Kant, I would propose the first question we should ask, is, What if this were perfectly ordinary?  Would anyone be deprived of consent or value?  Would people be able to retain their conscience?  And if the normal became compulsory, how much would those answers change?  (These are softened and naturalized versions of Kant's four forms of the Categorical Imperative)

Given that this is a very resource-intensive substance, at a certain level of consumption it can only be provided in a way that is extortionary.  How low is that level, and what are one's odds of a user remaining below that level?  We could explore that, and for a given individual it may be sustainable.  But the third point is the most relevant -- in general people are generally not free to chose their ultimate level of use, it is set by personality factors and biology.  Experience suggests that biology chooses an unmaintainable level for most of us.  So the substance itself sets up a contradiction that pulls users into an immoral state of inadvertent classism.

Users come to need this, and the average user cannot allow the price to reach its fair level, or they will physically suffer.  Yet they will be drawn to seek it out, and pay what they can.  So the market will not abate.

If this were more ordinary, therefore, the odds are quite high someone would get badly oppressed, whether or not the exact system that serves this problem now would arise in all of its intricate complexity.  Conscience probably could not be maintained.  And if experimentation with the substance became so common people really felt they were not participating in the society without taking part, many people would be put through painful withdrawals pointlessly.

So just going out and buying cocaine is a bad idea for a good reason.